# Dynamic queue operations

Tags: c#

I've encountered a problem with dynamic filed opearations...I have a method:

```
public Watcher GoToEnd(Watcher begin)
        {
            Watcher searcher = begin;
            while(searcher.Next =! null)
            {
                searcher = searcher.Next;
            }
            return (searcher);
        }
```

but I'm getting a error "Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'Back_Maker_3.Watcher' is less accessible than method 'Back_Maker_3.BMmain.GoToEnd(Back_Maker_3.Watcher)'"

Can someone see wham am I missing? I realy have no idea what's wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Watcher` class isn't `public` like your method, which exposes `Watcher` as both its return type and one of its arguments, which is not allowed.

You can either make the `Watcher` class `public`, or you can give `GoToEnd` the same accessibility as `Watcher`. I think you probably intended to make `Watcher` `public`, though.

Answer (score 1):

The method `GoToEnd` is `public`.  Since it returns a `Watcher`, The `Watcher` class must also be `public`.

By default I believe top level classes are `internal` and nested classes are `private`.  Not 100% sure on that since I always explicitly state the accessibility, which I believe to be good practice.

The reason for this is, that if `Watcher` was `internal` for instance, then code in a different assembly could call the `GoToEnd` method, but it wouldn't be able to use a `Watcher` object because it can't access it.